# How to interpret the difference between degrees of freedom estimates from a a non parametric gam() regression in R

Tags: regression, nonparametric, degrees-of-freedom, generalized-additive-model

I have run a multiple non-parametric regression using the gam function, my output is below. My question is - what can I conclude from the estimated degrees of freedom of USGDP compared to Rr (Rr is the Dollar price in South African Rands) as they relate to estimating Manufacturing?

model.np = gam(Manufacturing ~ s(Rr) +s(USGDP),
              data = d,
              family=gaussian())

[image]